# Mongod command not found (Windows7)(node.js)

Tags: node.js, git, bash, mongodb

I have been trying to get my mongodb going for about a day now. The problem seems to be that the mongod command is not found. I have the npm package mongoose installed in my node.js build. When i try to start the server with the mongod command the git bash returns that the command is not found.

I have been googleing for an answer and it looks like i need to make mongodb into a command, i'm not sure how to do this. Any advice would help.

I have downloaded the mongodb into my files it's located here C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0 ( Not sure if that matters or not).

Really not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Is the dircectory where mongod resides in the path? If it isn't you need to specify the full path - something like `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\mongod.exe`

Comment: That file is in there. Do i need to make C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\mongod.exe connected with mongod command?

Comment: What do you call `mongod command`?

Comment: a detailed answer is here, it's helped me a few times i have had to install mongodb on a new machine:  https://dangphongvanthanh.wordpress.com/2017/06/12/add-mongos-bin-folder-to-the-path-environment-variable/ , originally shared by user in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51461662

Answer (score 21):

Add the mongo's path to the `PATH` environment variable.

Reference: https://youtu.be/sBdaRlgb4N8?t=120

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a video just like this.

Comment: Is does this not happen automatically? That would be quite useful.

Comment: Is this specific to Windows? i.e. if we were running this on Ubuntu would there be a similar process that you know of? Just out of curiousity because I run a lot of development on Ubuntu using Virtual Box

Comment: I just downloaded mongo 4.0.2 and neither `mongo` nor `mongod` are in the bin folder at `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin` -- any ideas why that might be and how i can fix it?

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `./` to run `mongod.exe` file. use `./mongod.exe` It'll run successfully.

Answer (score 5):

When you open the bin folder it has a file called **mongod.pdb** instead of **mongod.exe** But don't worry. It could be rectified by adding the path to the environment variables. By appending the path of the bin folder (*C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin*) you are allowing the computer to run the executable files in that particular folder.

Answer (score 1):

**Set the path variable.**
When you open the bin folder it has a file called **mongod.pdb** instead of **mongod.exe** But don't worry. It could be rectified by adding the path to the environment variables. By appending the path of the bin folder *(C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin)* you are allowing the computer to run the executable files in that particular folder.

**shutting down with code:100**

When you run **mongod.exe** if the DB is **shutting down with code:100**, then you need to make two folders (*data and db*) to create databases. 
Use mkdir C:\data\db